# UIWebview don't store .aspxauth cookies on NSHTTPCookieStorage?

Tags: cookies, uiwebview

When I log on a login.aspx page in the UIWebview, I can handle the anonymous cookies but not the second cookies that allow me to connect.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem

```
NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookieJar = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
for (cookie in [cookieJar cookies]) {
   NSLog(@"%@", cookie);
}
```

shows all the cookies, including the asp.net_sessionId cookie ,
but the .ASPXAUTH not passed